# How to convert a CFL to a deterministic PDA?

Tags: turing-machines, regular-languages, pushdown-automata

I am trying to complete this question. However, I am unsure of the steps necessary to complete the conversion from a CFL to a deterministic PDA.

I know that $ww' | w \in \left \{ a,b \right \}^{*}, w' \in \left \{ b,c \right \}$ is a context free grammar.

I need to create a deterministic PDA diagram.

What steps do I need to complete in order to convert to a deterministic PDA?

[image]

Comment: There is no such conversion in general, since some context-free languages cannot be accepted by deterministic PDAs.

Comment: You write that the language $L$ in the problem is a context-free *grammar*. However, this is false. This is a context-free *language*, and it *has* a context-free grammar; but in and of itself, it is *not* a context-free grammar.

Comment: My apologies I meant CFL not CFG.

Comment: Is it possible to convert to Non-deterministic PDA?

Comment: A language is context-free, *by definition*, if it is accepted by some (nondeterministic) PDA.

Comment: Your particular language is accepted by a deterministic PDA.

Comment: What will this particular language look like in deterministic PDA?

Comment: It's essentially the PDA for $\{a^nc^n : n \geq 0\}$, ignoring $b$'s.

Answer (score 0):

The deterministic PDA has two states. In the initial state, whenever it reads $a$, it pushes $A$ into the stack, whenever it reads $b$, it does nothing, and whenever it reads $c$, it pops $A$ from the stack and moves to the second state. In the second state, if it reads $a$, it gets stuck, if it reads $b$, it does nothing, and whenever it reads $c$, it pops $A$ from the stack. The PDA accepts the word if it is in any state and the stack is empty.

(The exact definition depends on your PDA model. You need to take additional care to handle strings in $b^*$.)